# Casting operator-overloading to return 2-dim array to access external library

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

```
class M33
{
public:
    double m[3][3];

    double (*GetM())[3] {
        return m;
    }
};

// call to JPL cspice f2c generated routine
// void mxm_c ( const double   m1  [3][3],
//              const double   m2  [3][3],
//              double         mout[3][3] )

void test()
{
    M33 m1;
    M33 m2;
    M33 mOut;
    mxm_c( m1.m, m2.m, mOut.m ); // this works
    mxm_c( m1.GetM(), m2.GetM(), mOut.GetM() ); // this works
}
```

Using VS2013.
Question: Is it possible to use a casting operator such as...

```
operator double*[3] () // this does not compile
{
    return m;
}
```

thereby allowing this coding style shortcut?

```
mxm_c( m1, m2, mOut ); // this does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do such an operator. When complex types are involved, it's best to introduce an alias:

```
using Ptr = double (*)[3];

operator Ptr()
{
    return GetM();
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ec2abbf423bf8c3)